# Join tables with different character sets

Tags: oracle, join, collation, character-set

I am trying to join Table 1 from Database 1 to Table 2 from Database 2.
Database 1 and Database 2 have different character sets.
When I perform a join, I get the ORA-29275 error (partial multibyte character). I understand that this is due to the character sets / collations being different.

Is it possible to join Table 1 to Table 2 without changing the collation / character sets of either database? I tried `cast()` or `substr()` - that doesn't help.

Character set db1: `WE8ISO8859P1`
Character set db2: `UTF8`

Query:
`SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES@DB1 e1
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES@DB2 e2
ON e1.SURNAME = e2.SURNAME`

Data types:
`e1.SURNAME` = varchar2(78bytes)
`e2.SURNAME` = varchar2(40bytes)

Comment: What are the character sets of the two databases? What is the data type of columns you join? What is your query?

Comment: Character set db1: WE8ISO8859P1
Character set db2: UTF8

Query:
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES@DB1 e1
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES@DB2 e2
ON e1.SURNAME = e2.SURNAME

Comment: Try `JOIN ... ON CONVERT(e1.SURNAME, 'UTF8') = e2.SURNAME`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit That doesn't help. When I do `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES@DB1 e1
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES@DB2 e2
ON e1.ID= e2.ID`, it throws the same error. Now, if I do just `SELECT ID FROM EMPLOYEES@DB1 e1
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES@DB2 e2
ON e1.ID= e2.ID` that doesn't throw the error. Seems that it's an issue with displaying results in the same table.